# Retrieving table data from the <description> of multiple points in a kml file

Tags: beautifulsoup, kml

I am trying to extract the table data stored within a KML file. There are hundreds of points in this file and each point has a table embedded in its 'description'. I need the data for each point in a format that can be put into a csv or excel file.

Each table is formatted with the same headers designated by the th tag and then the data is designated with the td tag. I have included a copy of the code below.

I am attempting this with BeautifulSoup and have attempted a few different iterations, but am still quite the beginner here. I just get a blank return each time. I'd like the final result to end up with a string of all of the data, but with each element from a single table separated with a ',' and in a row and then the next table starting on a new line.

`node = soup.find_all('description')
header = node.find_all('th')
info = header.find_all('td')`

```html
  <Placemark id="ID_00004">
   <Snippet maxLines="0"></Snippet>
   <description><![CDATA[<html xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

<head>

<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

</head>

<body style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;overflow:auto;background:#FFFFFF;">

<table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;padding:3px 3px 3px 3px">

<tr style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;background:#9CBCE2">

<td> </td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>

<table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-spacing:0px; padding:3px 3px 3px 3px">

<tr>

<th>FID</th>

<td>4</td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">

<th>COLnum</th>

<td>14</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<th>Fieldnum</th>

<td></td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">

<th>Country</th>

<td>USA</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<th>State</th>

<td>Montana</td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">

<th>County</th>

<td>Dawson</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<th>Age</th>

<td>Upper Cretaceous</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<th>Stage</th>

<td></td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">

<th>AgeDate</th>

<td></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<th>Zone</th>

<td></td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">

<th>Map</th>

<td></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<tr>

<th>fauna</th>

<td></td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">

<th>Collector</th>

<td>C.A. White</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<th>Date</th>

<td>1882</td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">

<th>FaunaIndex</th>

<td></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<th>Reference</th>

<td>Monograph 32</td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">

<th>Comments</th>

<td></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<th>F22</th>

<td></td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">

<th>F23</th>

<td>&lt;Null&gt;</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<th>F24</th>

<td></td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">

<th>F25</th>

<td></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<th>F26</th>

<td></td>

</tr>

</table>

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</body>

</html>]]></description>
   <styleUrl>#IconStyle00</styleUrl>
   <Point>
    <coordinates>-104.5651611501076,47.2247073758612,0</coordinates>
   </Point>
  </Placemark>
```